# Issues with presenting view controller from another view controller in swift

Tags: swift, presentviewcontroller

I'm having trouble presenting a view controller from another. The only way I've been able to achieve this is with this line of code:

```
UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController?.present(partyMemberPage, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

Here is that whole function:

```
func partyMemberPage() {
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    let partyMemberPage = PartyMemberPage(collectionViewLayout: layout)
    UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController?.present(partyMemberPage, animated: false, completion: nil)

    print("from SplitButton")
}
```

Even though the code above works I am curious why the code below doesn't work. Everything I try, I get an error saying that I need to initialize `UICollectionView` with a non-nil layout parameter.

```
self.present(partyPage, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I'm almost positive I have the right items to use `self.present()`, but I can't get it to work on this vc.

PS: I'm also curious when is it a good idea to change the `rootViewController` (like the first line of code) and when it's acceptable to just modally present viewcontrollers. My app will deal with storing a small amount of data so what is the best way to transfer that data long term.

All help is greatly appreciated. I can provide more code if needed. I'm very new to swift and programming in general so forgive me if some of the logic is flawed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should not call the root window to present a view controller unless you absolutely have to. Essentially think of you view controllers as tabs in a browser window. Going back to the window like that is like clearing out all your tabs (sorta).

As for why `self.present()` is not working there could be a few reasons.

If you are using storyboard you need to reference your view differently :P

Also try with `self.present()` again, if it's throwing an error read up on it or post it with your question

The `completion: nil` is unnecessary.

Since I don't know exactly what your situation is I'll give you few options. I'll refer to the first view as VC1 and the second view as view VC2

1. Wrap VC1 in a navigation controller then try using .push()
2. Wrap VC2 in a navigation controller like so: (I'm using this code in my own project so I can verify it works)

```swift
 let loginView = UINavigationController(rootViewController: LoginViewController())
            loginView.modalTransitionStyle = .flipHorizontal
            self.present(loginView, animated: true)
```

3. Specify a modal transition as I have above

Comment: Thanks so much for that info! It's super helpful for a beginner like me. I should've mentioned that I am not using the storyboard at all. I changed my VC1 to a UINavigationController in my app delegate with this code:         `window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        let headerController = HeaderController(collectionViewLayout: layout)
        window?.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: headerController)`
Then when I try .push nothing happens.

Comment: Also when I wrap VC2 in a `UINavigationController` (as you have in your post) Xcode says I need to define a non-nil layout parameter, even though I think I do. Here is my code for reference:  `let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
  let partyPage = UINavigationController(rootViewController: PartyMemberPage(collectionViewLayout: layout))
  partyPage.modalTransitionStyle = .flipHorizontal
  self.present(partyPage, animated: true, completion: nil)`

Comment: @joker449  you need to define your layout you. can’t just initialize it empty by calling `UICollectionViewFlowLayout() `